# ODE: Why do we change our variable here?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve a matrix equation

$\dot x = Ax + Bu$

Rearranging yields

$\dot x - Ax = Bu$

Let $I = e^{-At}$ our integrating factor

so $d(xe^{-At})/dt = e^{-At}Bu$

Then $xe^{-At}$ = $x_0 + \int_0^t e^{-At}Bu(t) dt$

so our final solution is

$x = x_0 e^{At} + e^{At}\int_0^t e^{-At}Bu dt$

But the correct answer shows that I should instead make a change of variable some where so that the final solution is 
$x = x_0 e^{At} + \int_0^t e^{A (t-\tau)}Bu(\tau) d\tau$

Does anyone know why I need to have two separate variables? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a notational issue, but it is important and deserves careful attention. What you've written doesn't actually make sense, because you are using the same symbol for the integration variable and the limit variable. You should never do this; it is very confusing for exactly situations like this, and precisely speaking it just makes no sense (even though often people will know what you meant).

In the step where you integrate both sides, you should instead write it like:

$$x e^{-At} = x_0 + \int_0^t e^{-As} B u(s) ds$$

(or whatever integration variable you like, $\tau$ is just as good as $s$). Now when you multiply out the $e^{-At}$ you get the desired expression. You should always use a dummy variable like this whenever you write an integral with variable limits.